# Modify params before saving domain object

Tags: grails, grails-orm, grails-2.0, grails-domain-class, grails-controller

I needed a domain class that held a list of `Strings`.  It seems fairly well-known that GORM can't handle this, so I've worked around it.  At first I tried using getters and setters in the domain class, but that caused problems.  Then I found on Stack Overflow a way to use `afterLoad()` and `beforeValidate()` to rewrite properties as shown below.  This has worked well to allow me to turn the `List` into a `String` for persistence and back to a `List` for use in the app.

```
    class Entries {
        // persisted to database
        String _entry

        // exposed to app
        List entry

        static transients = ['entry']   //don't try to persist the List

        def afterLoad() {
                            // split the String from the database into a List
            entry = _entry?.split('\\|')
        }

        def beforeValidate() {
                            // join the List into a String for persisting
            _entry = entry.join('|')
        }

        static constraints = {
            _entry maxSize:4000
        }
    }
```

This works fine programmatically.  The only problem is that the Grails scaffolding can't deal with this, even if I try to enter a pipe-delimited string.  I understand the reason why is that the scaffolding creates a form field for `_entry`, so `entry` is null when it tries to save the object.  And `beforeValidate()` relies on a List of Strings to work.

I tried to get around this in the controller, by setting `params.entry = params._entry`, prior to the call to `new Entries(params)`.  [I recognize that this is not a perfect solution, but this was my first pass at getting the form working.]  And then I added a test in `beforeValidate()` to set `entry = _entry` if `entry` was `null`.  Basically:

EntriesController.groovy:

```
params.entry = params._entry    // I added this line
def entriesInstance = new Entries(params)
```

Entries.groovy:

```
    def beforeValidate() {
        if( entry == null ) entry = _entry    // I added this line
        _entry = entry.join('|')
    }
```

I thought that would allow me to enter pipe-delimited strings into the scaffolded Create Entries form and get *something* into the database.

To my surprise, though, I found that both `entry` and `_entry` were `null` in `beforeValidate()`, even though I printed and verified that `params` contained both keys in the controller.  I don't understand why this happens.  How did my adding a new key to `params` result in nulls arriving in the domain class?

The follow-up question is, of course, what's the right way to make the scaffolded Create Entries form accept a pipe-delimited String that makes it into the database?

Answer (score 2):

> I needed a domain class that held a list of Strings. It seems fairly well-known that GORM can't handle this, so I've worked around it.

I don't agree with you here

```
class Xyz {

static hasMany = [entries: String]

}
```

Should create a seperate table to hold your list of strings (It will actually be a Set). Here are the [docs](http://www.grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#5.2.1.4%20Basic%20Collection%20Types)

Comment: Well, that's good to know.  Apparently, I was looking at dated information.  I see, though, that scaffolding can't handle this.  Is there a workaround?  

I appreciate you bringing this to my attention, and I'll vote up your answer.  But I'd still like an answer to my question, since I don't understand what's happening with the params array.

Comment: I don't understand either, but expecting anyone to attempt to replicate the nonsensical code you have above is unreasonable.

Comment: (Thanks for noticing.  Only two more such expectations, and I earn the Unreasonable Badge.)  Why is it nonsensical?  It seems like a legitimate question to me.  Even if the hasMany approach avoids the problem, I would still expect to be able to manipulate the params map and have it work.  I'd like to know why it doesn't.

Comment: It's nonsensical because its a hack. Grails works very well when you follow the conventions set by Grails. As soon as you stray from that you are going to have a hard time. My point was that I can't immediately see why your code doesn't work, so expecting anyone to create a new project with your code to attempt to replicate it is not realistic.

Comment: My question has nothing to do with the hack.  The hack may be how I found the question, but I want to understand why a change to the params array in the Controller does not make its way to the Domain.